# file upload using php, ci and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

*I want to upload a multiple file but i get an error showing Undefined file. But the same code is working in another controller.I googled about it but i don't get any solution for this. Below u find the error details*

```
function upload($name = null){
    $fileName = uniqid("ePRIMA");
    $fname    = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
    $ext      = pathinfo($fname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $baseName = $fileName.".".$ext;
    $config['upload_path'] = _UI;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|xls|xlsx|doc|docx';
    $config['file_name'] = $baseName;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload($name)){
        $result['status']=1;
        $result['error']="Successfully added documents.";
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    return $baseName;
}

function uploadfile($id){
    $fieldName = array("File");
    $countarray = count($_FILES['FILES']['name']);
    $update = false;
    if($countarray!=0){
        for($i = 0; $i<=$countarray; $i++){
            @$fileName = uniqid("ePRIMA");
            @$file     = $_FILES['FILES']['name'][$i];
            @$ext      = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            @$baseName = $fileName.".".$ext;
            if(!empty($ext)){
                @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILES']['tmp_name'][$i], _UI.$baseName);
                $data = array("Demand_id"=>$candidateId);
                $data['File'] = $baseName;
                if(!empty($baseName)){
                    if ($this->candidate_model->add('demand_document', $data) == TRUE){    
                        $result['status']=1;
                        $result['message']="Successfull added certificates.";
                        $update = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($fieldName as $tempName){
        $fileName = $this->upload($tempName);
        $data = array("Demand_id"=>$id);
        $data[$tempName] = $fileName;
        if(!empty($fileName)){
            if ($this->candidate_model->add('demand_documents', $data) == TRUE){
                $result['status']=1;
                $result['message']="Successfull added ".ucfirst(strtolower($tempName)).".";
                $update = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($update == TRUE){
        header("Content-type: application/json", true);
        print_r(json_encode($result));
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>An Error Occured.</p></div>';
        $result['status']=0;
        $result['error']="Unable to upload file.";
        header("Content-type: application/json", true);
        print_r(json_encode($result));
        exit;
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: Notice</p>
    <p>Message:  Undefined index: File</p>
    <p>Filename: controllers/demand.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 284</p>
</div>
{"status":0,"error":"Unable to upload file."}
```

Comment: My first advice is to remove the silence operator (`@`). It just hides flaws in the code.

Comment: Also, you may want to remove the `foreach` on `$fieldName`, as it only contains one key.

Comment: i have already removed it